# errors in my main.dart on line 21 the return statement and error in my auth,dart on line 18 the map

Tags: flutter, firebase

main.dart

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/models/bro.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/models/bro.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return [https://www.mediafire.com/file/1faigtbe4o3k4dd/Capure.PNG/file]StreamProvider<Bro>.value(
        value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
 home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

auth.dart

```
[import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:lewandowski/models/bro.dart';

class AuthService{
  // method to sign in anon
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Bro? get bro => null;
  // create an object based on firebaseuser
  Bro? _userfromFirebaseUser(Bro user){
    return User != null ? Bro(uid:user.uid) : null;
  }
// change user stream

    Stream<Bro> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges
       [https://www.mediafire.com/file/qr6lr38khjgt456/Capture.PNG/file].map(_userfromFirebaseUser(bro!));
  }
  Future signAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return user;
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());

      return null;
    }
  }


  // method to sign in with email and password

  // method to sign up with email and password

  //method to sign out


}][1]
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/main.dart:21:37: Error: Required named parameter 'initialData' must be provided.
return StreamProvider.value(
^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.3/lib/src/async_provider.dart:102:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
StreamProvider.value({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/services/auth.dart:18:10: Error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'Stream<User?> Function()'.

- 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.9.0/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.
  .map(_userfromFirebaseUser(bro!));
  ^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Development\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\Development\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

bro.dart

```
class Bro{
   final String uid;
  Bro({required this.uid});
}
```

Comment: can you post the debug response correctly and show the line where it fails

Comment: in the main.dart its on  'StreamProvider<Bro>.value' and in the auth it the .map method '.map(_userfromFirebaseUser(bro!))'

Comment: i have added image links for the errors in the code